# Android - DatePickerDialog - Old APIs

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

I am trying to create a `DatePickerDialog` in my app in Android but when I create a `DatePickerDialog` I receive the following message: `Call requires API level 24 (current min is 14): android.app.DatePickerDialog#DatePickerDialog`

How can I use a `DatePickerDialog` in old API versions?

Comment: Which imports did you use?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use one of the [constructors](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html#DatePickerDialog(android.content.Context,%20android.app.DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener,%20int,%20int,%20int)) added in API level 1, not one of those added in API level 24.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works from API level 1:

```
val cal = Calendar.getInstance()   // used for initializing the date picker
val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(requireContext(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { datePicker, y, m, d ->

    // get user's selected y, m and d here

},
    cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
    cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
    cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
)
datePickerDialog.show()
```